# How to find count of comparisons in method sort()

Tags: python

I have a list in python. I need to find count of comparisons, which doing func sort(), when i'm using it. How can i do this?
Thank you.

Comment: Put some code to know what you have tried so far?

Comment: python2 is easy. python3 is harder but it can be done by using a key function that wraps the items.

Comment: i need to do it in python 3. i just use functools.cmp_to_key, and use it as key parameters. i find it in original docs of python. its  easy, but i needed for idea :) also, decorator -- good idea too:3

Comment: Note that the `cmp` argument used in Andrew Luo's anwer is deprecated; it's still available in Python 2, but it is _not_ available in Python 3.

Comment: Of course, you can get the same functionality of `cmp` in Python 3 by using `functools.cmp_to_key`, so both my and Andrew's answers are still applicable. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use the cmp function in sorting:

```
count = 0
def counter(x,y):
    global count
    count = count + 1
    return cmp(x,y)

sorted(mylist, cmp=counter)

print count
```

Comment: Using a global for the count breaks modularity. Also, `cmp` is not available in Python 3.

Answer (score 4):

This is one of those situations where using a function attribute to provide a static variable makes sense. The code below uses a decorator to add such an attribute to any function that doesn't take keyword args, but it's easy enough to adapt it to allow keyword args.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

''' Decorator demo

    Add an attribute to a function that tracks how many times it gets called

    Written by PM 2Ring 2014.10.22
'''

def counterize(f):
    def func(*args):
        func.count += 1
        return f(*args)
    func.count = 0
    return func


@counterize
def add(x, y):
    return x + y


def main():
    print 'Count:', add.count
    print add(2, 3), add(10, 11)
    print 'Count:', add.count
    print add(add(12, 13), add(110, 111))
    print 'Count:', add.count


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**output**

```
Count: 0
5 21
Count: 2
246
Count: 5
```

So you can apply `@counterize` to a custom comparison function definition, or you can just call counterize directly, passing it the function you want to counterize. Eg, to use it with the built-in `cmp()`:

`mycmp = counterize(cmp)`

Now `mycmp` is a function with a `.count` attribute that calls `cmp()` internally.

Answer (score 0):

Define a comparison function that increments a counter variable (global or an instance variable for the object that owns the comparison function). Pass the comparison function as the key to the sort function. After the sort, query the counter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Python Profiler](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html) as a start.  The List.sort function also takes a function parameter that you may utilize to do the counting.