# Passing list objects as function arguments (not as default value), are there any pitfalls?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, parameter-passing

Don't know where I read this recommendation, but if I need to pass sequence of values as function arguments, I'm using tuple. Probably I'm doing it because it immutable and I was recommended to do so by reading some book or passing course. But now I need a function where list should be passed as argument (because I need to use `pop` inside of it). And now when I'm little more experienced then before, I just wondering, are there any problems in passing list as function argument?

I know that using a list as default value - isn't a good thing. But what about simple argument? Are there any problems that can happen after it, or the only rule that I should follow - do not use list as argument default value?

For example, doing something like this - isn't a good thing:

```
def hello(arg_string="abc", arg_list = []): 
    print arg_string, arg_list 
    arg_string = arg_string + "defg"
    arg_list.append("A")


for i in range(4): 
    hello()
```

Output would be

```
abc [] 
abc ['A'] 
abc ['A', 'A'] 
abc ['A', 'A', 'A']
```

But what if I want something simple, with or without changing the object but where can I be sure that I could document that I changed something:

```
def hello(arg_list = []): 
    for i in arg_list:
        print(i)


hello(["1","2","3"])
```

Output here would be:

```
1
2
3
```

Comment: so have you tried?

Comment: It would help people understand exactly what you're talking about if you add a small example to your question. Function attributes can be a convenient way of providing static storage to a function, but they aren't commonly used in Python.

Comment: Do you mean attributes or arguments? Attributes are those which are assigned by `.` and arguments are those inside the `()` when calling the function.

Comment: FWIW, here's an old answer of mine that has a function that uses a function attribute (`func.count`) for static storage: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26501218/4014959

Comment: sry. i mistook them. I meant argument

Comment: @Unbrok3n No problem, could you [edit] the question and maybe include a short example how you pass in the list. Just so that the question is self-explaining without reading the comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass a mutable object to a function the function can change the contents:

```
l = [1, 2, 3]

def bad_func(lst):
    lst.append(5)
    return lst

l2 = bad_func(l)
print(l)    # [1, 2, 3, 5]
print(l2)   # [1, 2, 3, 5]
```

Normally functions should indicate if they alter the input or not, so this might only be an issue when the function has no or only poor documentation.

However you can always pass in a copy or do the copy in the function if you change the input:

```
def well_behaved_func(lst):
    lst = lst[:]  # shallow copy because the function alters the input
    lst.append(5)
    return lst

l = [1, 2, 3]
l2 = well_behaved_func(l)
print(l)   # [1, 2, 3]
print(l2)  # [1, 2, 3, 5]
```

As a rule of thumb (there are exceptions) a function should only modify the input if it doesn't return anything - or should leave the input alone if it does return something.

Comment: What's that got to do with function attributes?

Comment: Yep, you are right. But if im using list only to loop through it or indicate that i changes something, then i don't break any clear code rools?

Comment: @PM2Ring Interesting, I read `arguments` not `attributes`. Probably because the question contained them in the places I expected "argument", for example: "if I need to pass sequence of values as function attributes, i'm using tuple". Sounds more like the OP mistook attribute and argument. Not sure...

Comment: @Unbrok3n If you don't modify the list then there's absolutely no problem. If you copy the list before the function modifies it it's also no problem. Just in case you modify the input **unexpectedly** then it could be a problem (except when you mention it in the function documentation).

Comment: I agree that the OP's description is a bit confusing, especially the stuff about passing a function attribute. And that's why I requested that they post some code.

Comment: sry. i mistook them. I meant argument. @MSeifert understood me correctly despite of the fact of my mistake